# Is it better to write 0.0, 0.0f or .0f instead of simple 0 for supposed float or double values

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello well all is in the title. The question apply especially for all those values that can be like `NSTimeInterval`, `CGFloat` or any other variable that is a float or a double. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm asking for value assignment not format in a string.

EDIT 2: The question is really does assigning a plain `0` for a float or a double is worst than anything with `f` a the end.

Comment: What's wrong with `0.` or `0.f`?

Comment: :) sorry I missed those... But you see my point?

Comment: I believe at 99% of the time, they don't make any difference. Compiler is smart enough to remove the unnecessarily cast or conversion.

Comment: Agree with xlc0212. I would add that making floats look different from ints/longs in your code is good practice though. Choose a style and stick with it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The basic difference is as :

`1.0` or `1.` is a double constant

`1.0f` is a float constant

Without a suffix, a literal with a decimal in it (123.0) will be treated as a double-precision floating-point number. If you assign or pass that to a single-precision variable or parameter, the compiler will (should) issue a warning. Appending `f` tells the compiler you want the literal to be treated as a single-precision floating-point number.

Comment: can a double be specified like floats with its f ?

Comment: if you use `long double` you need to use `%Lf`

Comment: if you use `double`use `%lf`

Comment: okay, Thanks. The question is however for value assignment not format in a string I wasn't clear.

Comment: What do you mean by ".0 rounds your decimal value"?

Comment: It took 30 minutes to understand his actual problem.... u can see my dozen of edits :p

Comment: I was talking about that by default any floating point literal `0.0` or `9.84384` is a double

Comment: Please, note, that for 64bit CGFloat is double now, so, when converting your app to 64bit, it can be a pain to remote all those 'f' postfixes

Comment: @Denis: We have to move with every new invention and changes in IT. and at times we use #ifdef OSX_Version 10.8 #elif OSXVersion10.9 etc, we can change our implementation. **Any ways your point is good enough, so giving it 1 up**

Answer (score 8):

If you are initializing a variable then it make no sense. compiler does all the cast for you.

```
float a = 0; //Cast int 0 to float 0.0
float b = 0.0; //Cast 0.0 double to float 0.0 as by default floating point constants are double
float c = 0.0f // Assigning float to float. .0f is same as 0.0f
```

But if you are using these in an expression then that make a lot of sense.

```
6/5 becomes 1
6/5.0 becomes 1.2 (double value)
6/5.0f becomes 1.2 (float value)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dig out if there is any difference to the target CPU running the code or the binary code it executes, you can easily copy one of the command lines compiling the code from XCode to command line, fix missing environment variables and add a -S. By that you would get assembly output, that you can use to compare. If you put all 4 variants in a small example source file, you can compare the resulting assembly code afterwards, even without being fluent in ARM assembly.

From my ARM assembly experience (okay... 6 years ago and GCC) I would bet 1ct on something like XORing a register with itself to flush it's content to 0.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a way of actually finding out what the compiler does

Comment: You can view the assembly in Xcode, click the button here (image: http://goo.gl/Olzvh) and assembly is near the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you use 0.0, .0, or 0.0f or even 0f does not make much of a difference. (There are some with respect to double and float) You may even use (float) 0.

But there is a significant difference between 0 and some float notation. Zero will always be some type of integer. And that can force the machine to perform integer operations when you may want float operations instead.

I do not have a good example for zero handy but I've got one for float/int in general, which nealy drove me crazy the other day.

I am used to 8-Bit-RGB colors That is because of my hobby as photographer and because of my recent background as html developer. So I felt it difficult to get used to the cocoa style 0..1 fractions of red, green and yellow. To overcome that I wanted to use the values that I was used to and devide them by 255.

```
[CGColor colorWithRed: 128/255 green: 128/255 andYellow: 128/255];
```

That should generate me some nice middle gray. But it did not. All that I tried either made a black or white. 
First I thought that this was caused by some undocumented dificiency of the UI text objects with which I was using this colour. It took a while to realize that this constant values forced integer operations wich can only round up or down to 0 and 1. 
This expession eventually did what I wanted to achieve:

```
[CGColor colorWithRed: 128.0/255.0 green: 128.0/255.0 andYellow: 128.0/255.0];
```

You could achieve the same thing with less .0s attached. But it does not hurt having more of them as needed. 128.0f/(float)255 would do either.

Edit to respond to your "Edit2":

```
float fvar; 
fvar = 0;
```

vs ...

```
fvar = .0;
```

In the end it does not make a difference at all. fvar will contain a float value close to (but not always equal to) 0.0. For compilers in the 60th and 70th I would have guessed that there is a minor performance issue associated with `fvar = 0`. That is that the compiler creates an int 0 first which will then have to be converted to float before the assignment. Modern compilers of today should optimize automatically much better than older ones. In the end I'd have to look at the machine code output to see whether it does make a difference. 
However, with `fvar = .0;` you are always on the safe site.