# How to add up all objects (sum) of an array (with decimal) and display result in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, arrays, sdk, sum

Upon the development of my app, I have run into a little problem. I have an array, called priceArray, that the user adds objects to. In this situation, objects like @"1.50" or @"5.61" will be added. I have the following code to add them up, but it completely disregards the decimal. For example, if the array has two objects, @"1.50" and @"20.00", the label will show 21 instead of 21.50.

```
int sum=0;
for(int x=0; x < [priceArray count]; x++)
{
    sum += [[priceArray objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
}

budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", sum];
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sum` variable is an `int` type, so the decimal portion will be truncated (not rounded- simply dropped off). Instead, `sum` should be a `double` or `float` type.

```
float sum=0;
for(int x=0; x < [priceArray count]; x++)
{
    sum += [[priceArray objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
}

budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", sum];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but for example, using your code, when I enter 6.00 the label shows 6.0000000000...

Comment: Try this new code. The `%.2f` specifies 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much, to you, and everyone!

Comment: Nice answer, And one link that would help everyone here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302898/is-it-better-to-write-0-0-0-0f-or-0f-instead-of-simple-0-for-supposed-float-or/14302912#14302912

Answer (score 0):

You need to use float instead.

```
float sum=0;
for(int x=0; x < [priceArray count]; x++)
{
    sum += [[priceArray objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
}

budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%f", sum];
```

Integers are round numbers. 21 is round, 21.5 isnt round.

Answer (score 0):

follow this code -

```
float sum = 0.0;
for (int x = 0; x<[priceArray count]; x++)
{
    sum += [[priceArray objectAtIndex:x] floatValue];
}

budgetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",sum];
```

I hope this will help you.