# CGFloat Returning +Inf

Tags: ios, objective-c, infinity, cgfloat

I'm calculating the percentage of a number like so:

```
CGFloat total = 9;
CGFloat onePercent = total / 100;

CGFloat otherNum = 2;
CGFloat otherNumPercentage = otherNum / onePercent;
```

The result should be `22.2` repeating. However, it returns `+Inf`, which I believe is infinity.

I didn't think it would be treated as infinity as `22-23` certainly doesn't count for infinity, however is it because of the forever recurring `.2`?

Not sure how to handle this, how can I get my expected result?

Comment: Is your code written exactly as above? Are you sure none of those numbers are integers?

Comment: When you use constant numbers i.e. `9`, I had always assumed you needed to specify `9.0f` to indicate its a `float` rather than an `int`?

Comment: @Flexicoder that was it! Strange that we should have to cast it directly as an float as you specify, but that did resolve the issue. Thank you both for your input. Feel free to leave it as an answer and I'll give it a tick!

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct, according to this it should be a double. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15405182/488611

Comment: Your code above should work if total is a float. If total was an integer then it would not give the desired result because `total/100` would be done using integer math, yielding a zero, and then the zero would be converted to a float and stored in `onePercent`.

Comment: @JoshKahane a few extra reputation points are always useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use constant numbers i.e. `9` you need to specify `9.0f` to indicate its a `float` rather than an `int`

Comment: That is only true if the type is otherwise unclear to the compiler, e.g. if it's not part of a variable definition like it's the case here. Also, within arithmetic expressions such as `total / 100`, if `total` is not an `int`, `100` will be cast to `total`s type.